# Kafka streaming.Message reading order

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have topic, produced by jdbc connector with incrementing field. As known, records in this case written ordered by incrementing field. But when i read my topic by stream (foreach), i get records not ordered. Why?

Comment: I assume that you have multiple partitions? Order is only guaranteed within a partitions, but not across partitions.

Comment: Its bad (. I try to write some code, that checks that all rows from database are written to kafka at every moment.

Comment: It seems to be real, if i could count batch size between some values of  incrementing field in records in kafka and compare it with count rows in database.